# Ordering an SQL database through PHP

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to order a database by date but I am having trouble sorting it. The database is created in SQL through PHP and the column I want to use to sort by adds the date data in this format:

2011-10-26 07:10

The above date is also a 'varchar'. 
EDIT: changed to 'datetime' thanks to suggestions

Any idea so that I can sort the rows in the table using the date column?

I made a separate script to narrow this problem down:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("thoughtsdata",$con);


$order = "SELECT * 
FROM  `thoughts` 
ORDER BY  `thoughts`.`DateTime` ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30";

if(!mysql_query($order,$con))
{
die('Could not order database: ' . mysql_error());
}


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I now get no errors when running this script in my browser but my table remains unsorted:

```
  Edit    Inline Edit     Copy   Delete Hey sdfasdf    2011-10-26 19:41:00
  Edit    Inline Edit     Copy   Delete Hey asdfasdf    2011-10-26 07:47:00 
  Edit    Inline Edit     Copy   Delete Hey dfasdfasdf    2011-10-26 19:47:00   
  Edit    Inline Edit     Copy   Delete aaa how to sort this    2011-10-26 07:54:00 
  Edit    Inline Edit     Copy   Delete aaa any progress!!??    2011-10-26 08:13:00 
  Edit    Inline Edit     Copy   Delete oh no!  grrr    2011-10-26 08:21:00 
  Edit    Inline Edit     Copy   Delete zzTOp   thinking about sorting this out!    2011-10-27 19:12:00
```

What seems to me happening, is that the database is sorted but it does not stay like that.

Comment: wow, thanks for the quick response. I was able to change the datatype easily in php to datetime...now I am having trouble sorting the table from the php script.   I have this line in php: mysql_query('SELECT * FROM thoughts', 'ORDER BY DateTime');

Comment: perhaps is did not execute the statement correctly

Comment: The correct syntax would be:  mysql_query("SELECT * FROM thoughts ORDER BY fieldname");

Comment: DateTime is the column name....is that the same as the fieldname?

Comment: Add any output from the script (including all errors) to your post.  If there is no output, check your web server error logs to find out what happened.

Comment: ok, I think I found the error log at /opt/lamp/logs

Comment: In a LAMP setup, you should check /var/log/apache2/error.log or something similar to that; log file locations depend on several factors like virtual hosts, linux distro, and how the sysadmin decided on setting things up.

Comment: there doesnt seem to be a log folder in the var directory. When I search lampp directory for error.log nothing comes up, but error_log produces some results. Does the error_log snippet I added above help?

Comment: You found the correct logs, but they're showing errors from how you used to have your query written (the way you have it in your first comment to this post).

Comment: ok, thank you for your patience. I made a new script and included it in its entirety. When I run it in the browser I get no errors, but if you look at the column DateTime, it is still out of order. See anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Run the query: "DESCRIBE thoughts".  Paste your output to the question post.  I'm not sure where else to go with this - the only other thing I can think of is that when you changed the datatype from VARCHAR to DATETIME, no conversion was run on the data that already existed in the table.  If the field is DATETIME and the data isn't corrupt, the database will correctly sort the field in whichever order you ask.

Comment: I think maybe I misunderstood SQL. I thought that if I make this query, to sort the database, that it would remain sorted. I think I should read more about SQL. Thanks for you help. My query works, but wont remain sorted I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using an order clause like this:

```
ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(fieldname) ASC
```

However, if your field is in `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm` format like it looks, an alpha sort should work correctly.  This is all under the assumption that you are working with an existing system and can't / aren't allowed to change the field's datatype.

Comment: I can change the fields data type, but I am having trouble sorting hte column from the php script I made. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you're actually sorting it in the script itself, look at PHP's usort() function: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Comment: hmm, I want to sort the data in the SQL table but from the PHP script. Here is what I have tried to execute:             mysql_select_db("thoughtsdata",$con);
$order = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM thoughts ORDER BY DateTime");

if(!$order,$con)
{
 die('Could not order database: ' . mysql_error());
}

Answer (score 1):

Better way to convert it, for ex. with php, to "normal" datetime/timestamp and than use sort.

Main reason to do it is it's far more faster than using sorting by string.

Answer (score 0):

You can CAST or convert the varchar to a real datetime, that is what it should of been since it is really a datetime.